How many nebula jumps in a nebula sector delays the rebels by a whole jump?
Jumping to 2 nebula jumps in a non-nebula sector delays the rebels by a jump.
How many nebula jumps in a nebula sector delays the rebels by a jump?

In nebula sectors, the game mentions that the rebels are prepared for the nebula, but there's still a bit of a slowdown; jumping to 5 nebula beacons delays the rebels by one hop.

I thought it was 5 but it is harder to tell versus the non nebula sectors.
